# Codeigniter: How to get specific object data?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

If we use `result_array()`, then we get data as an array. If I want to echo 7th `product_name` we can do it like the following code

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select * from Products");  
$res = $query->result_array();
echo $res[6]['product_name']
```

What should we do to echo 7th `product_name` if `$res` is an object??

```
$query = $this->db->query("Select * from Products");  
$res = $query->result();
//echo 7th product_name of $res
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

```
echo $res->row(6)->product_name;
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in my local and you can access `$query->result();` with key of the array `$res[6]` But accessing child of the array will get change

```
Reuslt Type         array access        access child element 
                        method
result_array()      $res[<key>]     $res[6]['product_name']
result()            $res[<key>]     $res[6]->product_name
```

---

as you asked in question **What should we do to echo 7th product_name if $res is an object??**; you can access 7th by

```
$res[6]->product_name
```

Comment: object/array keys are starting with 0 index, so 7th product should be $res[6]->product_name: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#CI_DB_result::row

Comment: maybe you could add the 0 index thing into your answer, I'm sure a lot of people mix that up all the time